# How can i access user infromation using FQL according to email id?

Tags: .net, facebook

i want to fetch the user information(from facebook) using FQL according to email...

select * from user where email='abc@xyz.com'

how can i use this in asp.net application through using some API..
(https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY.)

plz reply

kind regards....

Answer (score 0):

You can't email; is not an indexable field. Indexable queries from the user table include:

```
uid
name
username
```

Comment: i i m finding problem in searching through name  .problem is Session key invalid or no longer valid. errorcode 102.